# Button Hyperlinking in Animate ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-animate

I'm trying to make three buttons in Adobe Animate, using ActionScript. Here is the code I'm using for button 1:

```
button. addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
     navigateToURL(new
     URLRequest("https://website.com/"));
}



button2. addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
function mouseDownHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void {
     navigateToURL(new
     URLRequest("https://anotherwebsite.com/"));
}


button3. addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
function mouseDownHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void {
     navigateToURL(new
     URLRequest("https://yetanotherwebsite.com/"));
}
```

(The URLs are made up and only for demonstration purposes.) The code for button 2 and 3, as you can see, are exactly the same but on different layers. I also change the instance name at the start, the function name, and the URL for each button. But when I press CTRL + Enter, all the buttons lead to the same webpage (in this case "website.com"), which is the one I put in first. It should lead to the different URLs I put in, but they all just go to the same one. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: There's no problem with the code above. Please edit the question to provide the actual code to comply with MCVE principles: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve At the moment the **verifiable** aspect is in question.

Comment: Show the code for all 3 buttons, and verify that you instance names in Animate match your code in every relevant frame.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. @BadFeelingAboutThis, I checked and double-checked the names before I asked this question or I wouldn't have if that was the problem. Thanks for the tip anyways.

Comment: Your problem statement is very clear, thank you,  but you have not provided enough information to identify the problem.   I'd recommend pasting ALL the code for all 3 layers/buttons

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis there you go, all the code.

Comment: Thank you, now the problem is clear,  all three of your button have the same `mouseDownHandler` as their event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, although you've defined 3 separate handler functions for the 3 separate buttons, you are attaching the first handler function to all 3 buttons:

```
button. addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
button2. addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
button3. addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
```

What you mean to do is this:

```
button. addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
button2. addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler2);
button3. addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler3);
```

Though, as an aside, you could do it all with one handler function using the event's current target parameter to figure which button was clicked:

```
function mouseDownHandler(event:Event):void {
    var url:String;
    //event.currentTarget is a reference to the object that you attached the event listener to
    switch(event.currentTarget){
        case button:
            url = "https://website.com/";
            break;

        case button2:
            url = "https://anotherwebsite.com/";
            break;

        default:
            url = "https://yetanotherwebsite.com/";
    }

    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url));
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks so much! This is my first time using ActionScript, it seems like such a basic mistake!